# Unable to modify file as part of entry point command

Tags: bash, docker, sed

My `Dockerfile`'s entry point `CMD` executes a shell script to modify a local file based on an environment variable before executing my application (Flask). The shell script is like so:

```
cat static/login.html |  sed "s/some_match/some_substitute/g" > static/login.html
```

However, I am finding that the resulting file is zero bytes. Any ideas what might be going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem, but not explain it. Maybe other answers follow.

But here is a solution which fixes the problem:
Use a different file name for the output than for the input.

`cat input.txt | sed "s/a/b/g" > input2.txt`

Alternatively, use the -i.bak option.

`sed -i.bak "s/b/a/g" input.txt`

I can only speculate about what exactly is going on:
Maybe the output of your pipe is opened for writing (non-appending) before the input is read.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at this. Please see what worked for me above.